# Convert Image to blob in Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to upload images to Firebase storage from my expo application. Then I need to convert the URI to the blob that will be sent to firebase. I have tried both code samples below for the conversion but none of them is working and other answers on SO aren't specific to Expo apps.

## What I've tried

```
  const blob = await new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve( xhr.response );
    };
    xhr.onerror = function ( e ) {
      console.log( e );
      reject( new TypeError( "Network request failed" ) );
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open( "GET", uri, true );
    xhr.send( null );
  } );
```

I've also tried

```
const response = await fetch( uri );
const blob = await response.blob();
```

### Sample error code

childPath.split is not a function. (In 'childPath.split('/')', 'childPath.split' is undefined)

Comment: Could you please show some code for getting image path and code where you try to convert it to a blob?

Comment: I picked the image like this


`let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync( {
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [ 4, 3 ],
    } );`


Then passed **pickerResult.uri** to the function that handles conversion to blob.
I've included the code snippet in the question.

Comment: I can't see the code that gives you the error that you've mentioned in your question, need to see where you try to pass/use that ```pickerResult.uri```, thanks.